# For loops in matlab only iterate 128 times

Tags: matlab

I am trying to code a Laplacian edge detection filter in MATLAB.

I have 4 nested for loops. The first two iterate through each pixel in an image, and the last two iterate through a 9x9 matrix around that pixel. For every iteration, the code multiplies each cell of the matrix to its corresponding pixel and adds to the sum for the matrix.

The problem is that it seems that the first two for loops only iterate 128 times as seen in the top image [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjSZL.jpg)

I know there is no problem with the for loops because to debug, I set each pixel of the output image equal to the input image and it works fine as seen in the bottom image.

```
for x = 1: imgWidth
    for y = 1: imgHeight 
        sum = 0;
        for maskX = (-1 * n):(n)
            for maskY = (-1*n): (n)
                if ((x + maskX) >= 1 && (x + maskX) <= imgWidth && (y + maskY) >= 1 && (y + maskY) <= imgHeight) 
                    sum = sum + int16(IMG(x + maskX,y + maskY)) * int16(mask(maskX + n + 1,maskY + n + 1)) ;
                end
            end
        end
        finalValue = (sum - minSum)/mult;
        rFinal(x,y) = finalValue;
    end
end
```

The result should be the edges of the main image. If there is no edge, the pixel should have a value of 127 but if there is an edge, one side of the edge will be very dark, containing a lower pixel value and the other side of the edge should be bright and contain a higher pixel value. This is the case for the first block of 128x128 pixels, however the result is unexpected for the rest of the image. No matter what size image I enter, the result will only be correct for that small 128x128 block.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Could it be a memory overflow problem with MATLAB? I am getting less than 50% cpu usage on my computer when I run the program, so I doubt that is the problem. I also doubt there is something wrong with the code as I have looked over it and tested it multiple times, but if you find something please don't hesitate to point it out! Thanks!

Comment: If you had a memory overflow MATLAB would have thrown a red tantrum in your console and stopped. You would know it. If your code really do only as you described (which we can't be sure because your code is not complete and we cannot run it), it is because it is coded that way. The first thing I would check are the values of `imgWidth` and `imgHeight` just **before** you enter the loop.

Comment: Please complete your code, see [mcve]. Possible problems could be `n` being a `int8`. -- By the way, you should write simply `-n:n`, and you should also not cast your pixel values to `int16`, cast them to `double` which is MATLAB's native, most natural type. Everything works better if you use `double`!

Answer (score 0):

To filter your image `IMG` with a linear filer given by `mask` use [`conv2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv2.html):

```matlab
conv2(IMG,mask,'same');
```